# Is this the way to do this simple IF OR OR statement?

Tags: php

I have an `if` statement with a few `or`'s in it.

i.e.

```
if($count == 1  ||  $count == 3  || $count == 7) {  
    // do stuff
}
```

I'm just curious - is this the best way to do this? With this simple example above, is there a faster way to do this, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Do you have any performance problems related to this code if asking for faster way?

Comment: No performance problems, more just wondering if there was a shortcut to achieve the same. When there are 10 or statements in there it can be a bit lengthy and repetitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine. Alternately, you can use [in_array()](http://www.php.net/in_array), which is a bit cleaner and scales better:

```
if (in_array($count, array(1,3,7))) { ... }
```

Comment: Actually, this is about 4 times slower than the original example... granted it takes (on my server) 116ms vs 449ms to run a million times... It is much cleaner and readable though. With small amounts of data - speed would be negligible. With large things - in_array performance is very slow.

Comment: @Sergey well, such case seems never encounter large arrays, isn't it?

Comment: If you are sticking a million items in there, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Col, my point was not just to compare bunch of statements VS in_array, but to just demonstrate that in_array might not be an optimal solutions every time. For example, I once encountered a piece of code that did this for 100k elements. And it was in a loop inside another 400k iterations. After getting rid of in_array check - I was able to speed up the code 100+ times. So it all depends on what is a real application, as oposed to this synthetic example. In addition, original question was if there is a faster way, which it is not.

Answer (score 3):

The code you've written is fine. As Paul Schreiber says, there are various other options that are a little neater.

One thing you may want to think about (and I know this is just an example) is why the values you're checking are important. Do they all have some property in common that you're checking? If so, then stating the property symbolically may make the code easier for someone to understand. For example:

```
if (is_odd($x) && $x < 10) {
    //...
}
```

rather than

```
if ($x == 1 || $x == 3 || $x == 5 || $x == 7 || $x == 9 ) {
    //...
}
```

This is quite a contrived example, but hopefully you see what I'm getting at.

As a more concrete example, instead of doing something like:

```
if ($user->age > 65 
    || $user->years_of_custom > 3
    || $num_items > 5 ) {
       // Give this user a discount ....
}
```

you might want to do:

```
if (eligible_for_discount($user, $num_items) ) {
    // Give this user a discount
}
```

Even if you only use the function in this one place, this could increase the readability of the code. Obviously you have to use your judgment though, because you're increasing readability at the expense of having more lines of code to maintain, and that isn't always the right choice. If the conditions have little to do with each other, binding them up into a separate function might make no sense and make your code harder to follow, not easier. Focus on what your code actually means, and how a human being should understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign all possible value in an array and check using [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function

```
$array=array(1,3,7);

if (array_search($count,$array) !== FALSE)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement be better?

```
switch ($count) {
  case 1:
  case 3:
  case 7:
    echo "do stuff";
    break;
}
```

Comment: if the 1,3,7 and all these values are dynamic comes and in the variables or in array how could you change switch statment?